# cancelling email sent by mistake to Yahoo mailbox

Tags: email

I just sent and email to a Yahoo email address and I wasn't allowed to do so. All I wish is to have that email deleted from that person's inbox.

What can I do now? Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but that's not happening.

Comment: What I'd like to know is what doug could have sent to a "yahoo" account that he wasn't allowed to send...last I knew there weren't rules saying you couldn't send whatever you want to someone on a public email address (unfortunately for spam recipients)...

Comment: It could be company policy? Or perhaps thinking he sent something to a particular customer but sent it to another one instead, while attaching confidential information relating to the other customer?

Comment: Pure speculation, but if it was confidential information, the company might want to start looking into a self-packing encryption or a more secure way of distributing that information if a simple "whoops" can distribute sensitive data like that. Maybe he'll elaborate, but maybe not. Either way...no chance of getting that out of Yahoo's mail queue.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not the sysadmin for the remote mail server, there's not a lot you can do, other than send an apology or retraction or...whatever. I don't know what you sent that you wouldn't have been allowed to send.

You could start praying that your message looked like spam and got stuck in their spam filters, I suppose.

Since the other server is on yahoo, chances are you can't even contact their sysadmin and ask for a message to be deleted either.

Comment: As an admin I wouldn't even listen to a request to delete an inbound message, even if it was possible to do so before it was delivered.

Comment: Not if it were from another business contacting us, I'd agree. But if it's an internal user to another internal user, that's a different story. I was just musing on possibilities.

Comment: if it can't be deleted, can it be overwritten?

Comment: No. You have no control of a remote mail server that doesn't belong to you or your company. Otherwise people wouldn't just be hit with spam, they'd have bots actively deleting emails that were delivered. Once the message leaves your mail server it is out of your hands.